# Why a type method that should return a string returns a 'unit -> string' instead and how to solve it?

Tags: string, class, methods, f#

So I have this simple code, I'm trying to figure out classes and inheritance in F#:

```
type Mkp() =
    abstract tX : unit -> string
    default this.tX() = ""

type A(n : string, v : string) =
    inherit Mkp()
    member this.n = n
    member this.v = v
    override this.tX() = sprintf "%s = \"%s\" " this.n this.v

let test = A "first" "second"
let xxx = "" + test.tX
```

I get the compiler error: The type 'string' does not match the type 'unit -> string' but I expected test.tX to be a string, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Your class definitions are correct, but there are two small issues when you use them:

- When creating the instance, you need to pass parameters to the constructor as a tuple
  i.e. you need to say `A("one", "two")` rather than `A "one" "two"`
- When invoking a method, you need to specify empty parameter list i.e. `test.tX()`

The correct use of your class `A` looks like this:

```
let test = A("first", "second")
let xxx = "" + test.tX()
```