# ToArray and ToString return (unit -> string), not string. What should I do?

Tags: string, f#

Notes

- [Why a type method that should return a string returns a 'unit -> string' instead and how to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480416/why-a-type-method-that-should-return-a-string-returns-a-unit-string-instead) does not answer my question because it refers to incorrect input, while I do not have it.

I'm currently having a problem with the functions "ToString" returning a (unit -> string) type and not a string, and "ToArray" returning (unit -> string[]) and not string[]. Attempting to upcast to string[] or string has no success.

Here is the code:

```cs
let readZip filepath = ZipFile.OpenRead filepath
let replaceEnvs str = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables str

let listFiles rawDir =
    replaceEnvs rawDir
    |> Directory.EnumerateFiles

let readModMetadata filepath =
    let archive = readZip filepath
    (archive.GetEntry "mcmod.info").ToString    // Also becomes (unit -> string) and not string

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let mods = listFiles modsFolder
    let modAsArray = mods.ToArray   // Becomes (unit -> string[]) and not string[]?
    0
```

Why is this so, and is there a way to get only strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found it out.

You need to specify that no parameters go into the functions. The parenthesis in `ToString()` do just that, as they differentiate returning a function from returning a result.
I need more coffee.